# Pluck and ids give array of non unique elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ancestry

In console:

```
Course.ids.count 
=> 1766
Course.pluck(:id).count
=> 1766
Course.ids.uniq.count
=> 1529
Course.count
=> 1529
```

It's normal?

small comment - model Course uses ancestry (gem).

**UPD1:**

Generated sql:

```
Learn::Course.ids.count
(5.4ms)  SELECT "learn_courses"."id" FROM "learn_courses" LEFT OUTER JOIN "learn_course_translations" ON "learn_course_translations"."learn_course_id" = "learn_courses"."id"
=> 1766
Learn::Course.count
(1.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "learn_courses"
=> 1529
```

hmm...

**UPD2:**

Schema Information

```
#
# Table name: learn_courses
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  name        :string(255)
#  position    :integer
#  created_at  :datetime
#  updated_at  :datetime
#  ancestry    :string(255)
#  course_type :string(255)
#  article     :string(255)
#  item_style  :integer
#  hidden      :boolean
#  score       :integer          default(0)
#  next_id     :integer
#  first       :boolean
```

Comment: @MaxWilliams http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-ids

Comment: Can you look in your log and see what sql is generated by each of the different commands, and add them under each command in your question?

Comment: Also, what does your `Course` schema look like?

Comment: I'd call it at least "unexpected behavior", and open a bug on the ancestry github.

Comment: @Kristján I just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to work around this with

```
Learn::Course.pluck('distinct learn_courses.id')
```

The problem is that `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with `learn_course_translations`, which must have multiple rows per `Learn::Course`, resulting in the same `learn_courses.id` appearing several times. `pluck` doesn't care about distinctness, so it just passes them all back.

Comment: I see. Looks like you are right. One more point: `Learn::Course.pluck('distinct id')` returns `PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous`. But it does not matter, I realized what the problem is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `ancestry` adds `default_scope` to your model. Try to check it with

```
Learn::Course.unscoped.ids.count
```